# Web Scraping from a Website with a Static URL

Tags: python, html, url, static, web-scraping

So I am trying to extract postal code information from the [Canada Post Website](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/personal/postalcode/fpc.jsf?LOCALE=en). The issue I am having here is the URL remains static regardless of what address you enter when trying to find a postal code. For instance, starting at the base page, if I input '1 MACLEAN ST' as my search query, and hit enter

[image]

You will notice the URL remains the same

[image]

I have never web scraped from a website with a static URL before, and was wondering how I would go about doing this (eg. getting specific libraries for Python etc). I think at some point, I more than likely have to extract the postal code information (' A0J 1T0' in this case) through an html tag, as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper using something like [Selenium](http://scraping.pro/selenium-ide-and-web-scraping/) to interact with the page dynamically.

Alternatively, you may want to look into their developer API, which should allow you to provide an address and get back a code (as well as more advanced use cases like creating shipping labels).

https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/fundamentals.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to perform actions prior to scraping, you need to use a headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org). It's a bit more challenging than basic scraping, but it will allow you to type in addresses programmatically and then scrape the resulting data of the page that is returned.